# How might I animate randomly positioned elements such that they will not overlap

Tags: jquery, animation

I am thinking of trying to animate in/out elements at random times and position to create an effect like

http://jsfiddle.net/MEpVq/

except that currently, there will be alot of overlap, and it doesn't seem all that random

Answer (score 0):

Random is an illusion, there is no random in the world only situations where we don't understand the starting conditions, the process or both. I think the lack of 'randomness' you are seeing is perceptual rather than actual (within the bounds of the obscure sequence generated by the Random method), I don't think the elements are appearing more or less randomly than might be expected. Unfortunately when we humans think of random we tend to expect chaos. For example, if I ask you to think of two random numbers between 1 and 10, if I hadn't given you any criteria it's extremely unlikely (to the point of never) that you would give me the same number twice but "2" and "2" is a valid random sequence when picking the numbers from 1 to 10. You'll have also applied other logic to avoid what you perceive as patterns because you are expecting 'random' to be chaotic.

To avoid overlap you are going to need to take and store the location and rectangle (width, height) for each instance you create and the discard any new combination that would cause an overlap to occur. You are effectively restricting the 'randomness' of your process but your constraint, no overlap, but it's unavoidable given the requirements.

Answer (score -3):

There are probably two ways to get this done. The easy one would be to use a plugin like [jQuery RandPosPlugin](http://www.manuelmaurer.at/randposplugin.php) for instance, which I created a few weeks ago. The more difficult one would be to build this on your own. Therefore you'd need something to save all the coordinates of the elements - I'd use a standard array. Before you try to position the next element on a random position you can go through the array and check if there already is an element at that certain position - which means that you'd need to recalculate it. It needs some time and quite some testing but all in all it's not that difficult to achieve such an algorithm even with preventing overlapping on your own.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be careful with linking to your own content on different sites, you don't want to be a [spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You do not want to push your own plugin on every answer.